# Omnipay token billing not working with stripe

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, omnipay

I am using ignited/laravel-omnipay package for omnipay in laravel.
I am trying to implement token billing using stripe as shown here https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay#token-billing. 
Customer are getting created successfully on stripe but i am not able to make payment with the returned customer id.

Here's my code

```
    $token = Input::get('stripetoken');
    $gateway = Omnipay::create('Stripe');
    $gateway->setApiKey('My Key');
    $gateway->setTestMode(true);
    $cardresponse = $gateway->createCard(array('token' =>$token))->send();
    if ($cardresponse->isSuccessful()) {
      $card_id = $cardresponse->getCardReference();
      $data = $cardresponse->getData();
      $customerid = $data['id'];
      $cardid = $data['default_source'];
    }
    $paymentresponse = $gateway->purchase(array('amount' => '10.00','currency'  => 'USD', 'cardReference' => $card_id))->send();
    echo $paymentresponse->getMessage();
```

I am getting following response.

```
No such token: cus_8FwPaLNKdWcfRW
```

And when i check my stripe dashboard then customer with this id exists and has a card assigned.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're creating a customer object, you need to update your [charge creation request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) to pass the customer ID in the `customer` parameter rather than in the `source` parameter (which causes the error you're seeing).

I'm not familiar with Omnipay but I think this should work:

```
$paymentresponse = $gateway->purchase(array('amount' => '10.00','currency'  => 'USD', 'customerReference' => $card_id))->send();
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Omnipay should really work on there documentation.  Its too confusing. Thanks again.

Comment: really they need to work on their documentation